# Could not validate time whether is greater or lesser in erlang

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

Problem in **validating current time whether it is greater or lesser than time which is in 24 format** in erlang

scenario : have to auto reply after 3clk.

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail? Are dates involved in the comparison, too?

Comment: Take a look at [`calendar`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/calendar.html) module?

Comment: You have to auto-reply after 3 o'clock?

Comment: @BrujoBenavides, yes but time is dyncamically set from mysql.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, what you need is a function that tells you if at this moment we're past 3PM or not.

If that's the case, you can use something like this…

```erlang
-module date_utils.
-export [is_past_15/0].

is_past_15() ->
  {_, {Hour, _, _}} = calendar:local_time(),
  Hour >= 15.
```

Now if you get the time as a parameter, you can take advantage of the way in which Erlang sorts tuples…

```erlang
-module date_utils.
-export [is_past_15/0, is_past_1510/0, is_past/0].

is_past_15() ->
  is_past({15, 0, 0}).

is_past_1510() ->
  is_past({15, 10, 0}).

is_past(TimeLimit) ->
  {_, Time} = calendar:local_time(),
  Time >= TimeLimit.
```

Comment: Thank you sir, its working as i expected, one more help, How to i check 3.10 instead of 3 , because time come from Database dynamically.

Comment: Well… it depends on how do you get that time, but I'll amend my example to account for _some_ version of that.